# Django-url cmd server error

Tags: python, django

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from adoptions import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^$', views.home name='home'),
    path(r'^adoptions/(\d+)/', views.pet_detail, name='pet_detail'),
]
```

this is my code when I run python manage.py runserver...
It returns a syntax error.. saying third line in urlpatterns "name" error which is (name='home') here..

Comment: You missed one `,`

Comment: Yoohoo.... It worked... God bless you

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in WisdomPets.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    ^$ [name='home']
    ^adoptions/(\d+)/ [name='pet_detail']

The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: can you please tell me the error here?